# Identifying an Event based on a Jump in Rolling Variance in Python

Tags: signal-analysis, python

I am trying to figure out a way, in Python, how to identify when an event occurs, based on a jump in the rolling standard deviation.

As shown in the plot below, around the 12000th sample, an `event` occurs.  In my Python script, I am currently using a threshold of `0.00051` to signify when that event occurs.  However, sometimes the `event` occurs at `0.0005` and other times the `event` occurs at `0.000495`.

[image]

My question is - how can I algorithmically, in Python, detect this jump in the rolling standard deviation to create the event altert?  Because if I have a threshold set too low, I don't want it to be triggered too early.  And if I run another test, and the threshold is too high, then I don't want the event to not be triggered at all.

Any advice is greatly appreciated!

```
def animate(i):
    data = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\data.txt", sep="\[|\]\[|\]",engine = 'python', header = None)
    data = data.iloc[0, ::4]
    data = data.astype(str).apply(lambda x: x.split(',')[-1]).astype(float)
    data.pop(0)
    xar = range(len(data))
    yar = pd.DataFrame(data)
    # Starting from sample 1050 to get rid of any initial noise
    yar = yar[1050:12500]
    xar = xar[1050:12500]
    std = yar.rolling(window=2500).std() 


    if (np.any(std>.00051)):
        choices = ["Confirm Event"]
        reply = easygui.buttonbox("Event Alert!, image, choices)
        if reply == "Confirm Event":
            sys.exit(0)

    ax1.clear()
    ax1.plot(xar,std)
    ax1.set_title('Rolling Standard Deviation')       


fig, (ax1) = plt.subplots(1, sharex = True)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=.01)
plt.show()
```